# Install bit 64 RStudio

Tags: r, bit64

Good morning,
I am trying to install this package:

`install.packages("bit64")`

But I am receiving this error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'No se pudo establecer una conexión con el servidor'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.3:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES'
```

Comment: "no se pudo establecer" seems obvious enough - that site is not reachable from where you're doing the installation.

Comment: You can try installing from a different repository.  For example `install.packages('bit64', repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")`

Comment: Thank you, but it returns the same error.

Comment: I have pasted the urls in my browser and it is reachable

Comment: For older versions of R on Windows one has to call `setInternet2()` to use the other inet-stack.